# How to prevent adding same product to cart more then one time in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento development. I dont want user to add any product more then once to the cart.if he/she need to change the qty of the product then he/she need to change it from mycart page but add to cart button only allow once to add product, after that when he/she clicks on add to cart button it must say "it is already added to the cart if you want to change the quantity then please go to mycart".

for example you can see www.flipkart.com.

Comment: Is this really needed by your application for anything? Otherwise it's not really what usability stands for, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

Product -> Inventory -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

System -> Configuration -> Inventory -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

---

Have a look at [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Events you could use, are for example: `checkout_cart_update_items_before` and `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

Also I'd suggest looking atthe: `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` for other events that might be helpful.

In this file also, you'll find code like:

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->addError(
  Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Some of the requested products are unavailable.')
);
```

Which you could use for displaying the the error message to the customer.

Comment: @ yoshi i would like to display "The product is already added to your cart"....sorry for saying but i cant understand what are you saying, as i have not done too much work in magento, it will be easy for me you explain it at it deepest

Comment: @ yoshi...can you please help me a bit further...what process you are saying, can it really do the job what i am asking...actually i need any help on this....

Comment: @Shawkat I changed my answer, as I was too blind to see such a simple configuration option. Hope it helps  ;)

Comment: @ Yoshi thanks for the help..its really nice but sorry for saying there is a little problem, it is not allowing me to change the quantity in mycart page. i just want that if some one click twice on the "Add to cart button" for the same product it will show him "the product(Product name) is already added to your cart " and that time it will not allow the  product. but the quantity can be editable from mycart page. as it happens in magento by default. hope you understand what i am saying

Comment: @Shawkat Then I'm affraid you won't solve this without developing your own extension. I'll readd my previous answer, so you'll at least have a starting point for further reading.

Comment: @ Yoshi please help me ,give me some clue to do it.