# Magento - prevent adding the same sku twice or more

Tags: magento

I want to prevent users from adding the same product twice or more (in backend as well as frontend), whilst not restricting them from ordering as many items as they want.

For example, given there's a product with the SKU **ABCD123** - how do I prevent the user from adding it twice into the cart? Instead allow the user to add it once and let them update the ordered qty instead?

I had a look at this [How to prevent adding same product to cart more then one time in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545329/how-to-prevent-adding-same-product-to-cart-more-then-one-time-in-magento); however the solution suggested refers to restricting total number of items in cart or updating every product with a certain inventory config.

Is there a way to do this differently by modifying the cart code?

Comment: @Lathe... : You can use ajax to notify mentioning: "This product is already added , However the customer can update the product while checking out .." By the way magento also only updates the qty , it doesn't again adds a row of the same added earlier ..

Comment: If product has custom option and if customer can choose another custom option then product quantity will not updated

Answer (score 1):

If product has custom option and if customer can choose another custom option then product quantity will not updated in this case, if product is simple then quantity will update every time customer add to cart product

You can check if product with same sku is in cart or not using event observer.

You can use `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event to check if this product is already exist in your cart. below is highlight of code on how you can create even observer in magento.

your config file is look like this

```
<config>
...
<frontend>
    ...
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                    <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                    <method>CheckItem</method>
                </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
    ...
</frontend>
...
```

And in your observer check your logic if something is in cart or not

```
 class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer
{

        public function CheckItem(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
        {
            // Get the quote item
            $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
            //and put your logic here to match item with sku
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own module, you could try overwriting the `addAction` in the CartController:

```
class MyModule_MyCheckout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        // initialize product to add to cart
        $product = $this->_initProduct();

        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach($items as $item) 
        {
            if($item->getSku() == $product->getSku()
            {
               //add the same item
               Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->addItem($item);
               // set a message in the session
               return $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
        }

        parent::addAction();
    }
}
```

Essentially, you loop through your cart when stuff gets added and return when you find, that an SKU has been added already.

In your `config.xml`, the route for this module would have to be overwritten like this:

```
//<global>-Context
<rewrite>   
   <mymodule_mycheckout_cart>
       <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
       <to>/mycheckout/cart/</to>
   </mymodule_mycheckout_cart>
</rewrite>
```